# Google Cloud Storage host static website homepage not displayed

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

**Situation:**

I have followed the instructions from the official GCP documentation: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website

There are only two files within the bucket: index.html and error.html Both are also used as specialty pages as described within the documentation.

**Issue:**

- mydomain.io --> shows content of error.html
- mydomain.io/ --> shows content of error.html
- mydomain.io/index.html --> only this will display the content of index.html
  Is this the expected behavior?

I want to display the content of index.html for all three cases above. Everything else should display the error.html How can I do this?

Comment: Did you follow https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website#specialty-pages ?

Comment: Yes, I have mentioned it in my second paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

It is working now without changing anything. So patience is the solution :)

Comment: The likely reason that patience worked is that objects that are publicly, anonymously accessible in Cloud Storage have a default cache policy of one hour. GCS is strongly consistent, but cached reads aren't. This also means that if you replace `index.html` with new data, it may take up to an hour for that new version to show up. You can read more at https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/metadata#caching_data